# How to set wp-content/ folder permissions so all sub-directories take its permission?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, wordpress

wordpress uses the wp-content folder to store uploads, and the uploads are also stored in their own folder depending on the month you upload the file like:

```
wp-content/uploads/month/day/file.jpg
```

the folder needs 755 permissions and I believe on all sub-folders.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change existing files and folders:
`chmod -R 755 *`

to change future files
`umask 022`

Answer (score 1):

The folder only needs 700 permission.  All access should be done as the apache user (www-data on ubuntu).  To ensure the appche sets 755 permisions on directories ensure it is run with 'umask 022'.  It is important that the directory be owned writable by the web-server user.

It is more secure to have only the uploads directory writable by apache.  However, it means you will need to update themes, plugins, and languages by another mechanism.  The Ubuntu package uses /var/www/wp-uploads as the uploads directory.

Comment: I'm using nginx, so I guess I need to give www-data the permissions right?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you get the perms right on the wp-content/uploads folder the newly created subfolders should inherit them as they're created.